# add TDengine as data source in idea

Tags: database, intellij-idea

I add the the tdengine as idea data source, but i found some problems.
1.when i executed a query, after i got the result. The idea still execute the query.However compare with mysql, the idea execution terminated as long as the result returned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/696L8.png)
2.also compare with the mysql, i can just get information db and tables, and there isn't any [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76Xr0.png)information about the columns.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98Boh.png)

the exception of second image is

```
<failed to load>
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR (2315): unknown taos type in tdengine
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:69)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:56)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBConstants.taosType2JdbcType(TSDBConstants.java:131)
    at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBResultSetMetaData.getColumnType(TSDBResultSetMetaData.java:151)
    in RemoteResultSetMetaDataImpl.getFixedColumnType(RemoteResultSetMetaDataImpl.java:105)
```

Comment: use taos-jdbc dirver, the exception of the sencond image is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use taos-jdbcdriver-2.0.34 to solve this problem